# Validation Not Working in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to Mvc and I'm creating a web app and I'm stuck with a problem. In my app I've a signup page and i need to validate the given input but its not working my current code is given below

Model

```
public class Account
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is required")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "First Name length Should be less than 50")]
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Id is required")]
    [StringLength(35, ErrorMessage = "eMail Length Should be less than 35")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$", ErrorMessage = "Email Id is not in proper format")]
    public virtual string EmailId { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignUp(string userName,string email)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    Account newAccount = new Account();
                    var userExist = newAccount.UserExist(userName);
                    if (userExist == 0)
                    {
                        AccountBL createAccount = new AccountBL();
                        createAccount.UserName = userName;
                        createAccount.EmailId = email;;
                        newAccount.SignUp(createAccount);
                        return View("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();

                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

View

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Sign Up</legend>
                <table>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Label("User Name")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(account => account.UserName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(account => account.UserName)
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Label("Email")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             @Html.TextBoxFor(account => account.EmailId)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(account => account.EmailId)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Sign Up" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
```

I cant find anything wrong in my code so please point out whats wrong with my code

Comment: have you included jquery validation plugin in the client script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not passing your model back in the post method. Instead of passing the username and passwords as strings, try passing the model type that you bound to the View. Your post action method signature should look something like this:

```
public ActionResult SignUp(AccountModel model)
```